# Protect the Folder using Apache and Access that File using PHP

Tags: php, file, apache-config

HI, I want to protect only my documents folder in the Web server and I did by placing .htaccess file in that directory but how to access that file in my PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `Deny` in a `.htaccess` file will no effect on PHP -- which means you can access the files in your folder wih PHP [file-system functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

Answer (score 0):

to access the files you can use file_get_contents() or file() functions. There are many ways to access the files. is that what you looking for?